# Prevent parent from being clickable while allowing child to capture touches

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, mobile

In `react-native` sometimes it is useful to prevent a parent from capturing and handling touch / click events while allowing its children to receive and react to the events. Specifically, this is useful when using a `<View/>` or `<ImageBackground/>` container that acts as a transparent background to its child elements (example: gradient based shadows or wrapper views used to center elements of absolute positioning).

Answer (score 9):

React Native offers a `pointerEvents` prop for `<View/>` elements which can be set to `'none'` in order to stop reacting to touches and clicks, however the trick to allowing the children to still be touchable is to set the `pointerEvents` prop to `'box-none'` instead of `'none'`.

**Warning:** In contrast to regular CSS, `pointerEvents` is ` **prop** and not a **style**. So to use it, you can do

```
<View style={styles.parentWithoutTouchEvents} pointerEvents='box-none'>
   <View style={styles.touchableChild}>
   </View>
</View>
```